# Strict and homotopy unit in $A_\infty$ spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

Stasheff defines $A_\infty$ spaces with a unital multiplication and Boardman and Vogt define $WU$-spaces (an algebra over the $W$-construction of the associative operad) as a kind of $A_\infty$ space with homotopy unit.

I would like to know an example of a $WU$-space which does not admit a (strictly unital) $A_\infty$ space structure.